# python pandas: Grouping dataframe by ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe object with date and calltime columns.

Was trying to build a histogram based on the second column. E.g.

`df.groupby('calltime').head(10).plot(kind='hist', y='calltime')`

Got the following:
[image]
The thing is that I want to get more details for the first bar. E.g. the range itself 0-2500 is huge, and all the data is hidden there... Is there a possibility to split group by smaller range? E.g. by 50, or something like that?

## UPD

`date    calltime
0   1491928756414930    4643
1   1491928756419607    166
2   1491928756419790    120
3   1491928756419927    142
4   1491928756420083    121
5   1491928756420217    109
6   1491928756420409    52
7   1491928756420476    105
8   1491928756420605    35
9   1491928756420654    120
10  1491928756420787    105
11  1491928756420907    93
12  1491928756421013    37
13  1491928756421062    112
14  1491928756421187    41
15  1491928756421240    122
16  1491928756421375    28
17  1491928756421416    158
18  1491928756421587    65
19  1491928756421667    108
20  1491928756421790    55
21  1491928756421858    145
22  1491928756422018    37
23  1491928756422068    63
24  1491928756422145    57
25  1491928756422214    43
26  1491928756422270    73
27  1491928756422357    90
28  1491928756422460    72
29  1491928756422546    77
... ... ...
9845    1491928759997328    670
9846    1491928759998255    372
9848    1491928759999116    659
9849    1491928759999897    369
9850    1491928760000380    746
9851    1491928760001245    823
9852    1491928760002189    634
9853    1491928760002869    335
9856    1491928760003929    4162
9865    1491928760009368    531`

Comment: you can use df.hist() with bins parameter

Comment: Aha, it's already better. But can I also somehow add values to X scale, so it's visible which ranges the bar has?

Comment: Its difficult to visualize without the data, can you post the output of df.groupby('calltime').head(10)?

Comment: Added more info about the range

Comment: Ok so you can sort the data by ascending = false and take top rows to reduce the range

Comment: A bit strange. I can't get top rows... e.g. df.sort_values(by='calltime', ascending=False).groupby('calltime').head(2).plot(kind='hist', y='calltime', bins=12) does not give them

Comment: I don't see the purpose of groupby('calltime') here, they are unique values.

Comment: Well they are unique. But I want to somehow know how many calls was executed for example faster then 100ms, 200ms, etc... So I thought group by will somehow group items by calltime ranges

Comment: Shall I use cut instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `bins`

```
s = pd.Series(np.abs(np.random.randn(100)) ** 3 * 2000)
s.hist(bins=20)
```

[image]

Or you can use `pd.cut` to produce your own custom bins.

```
pd.cut(
    s, [-np.inf] + [100 * i for i in range(10)] + [np.inf]
).value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

[image]